# Can anyone explain to me this python syntax on urlparse?

Tags: url

The line is:

> url = f'{protocol}://{host}'

and the error is:

> ```
> url = f'{protocol}://{host}'
>                            ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Any clue will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.6 added a new kind of string literals: f-strings, or formatted string literals ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals)). You are seeing this error because you are using an older version of Python which doesn't understand this syntax.

The `f` prefix specifies that this is an `f-string`. The `{protocol}` and `{url}` are expressions which are replaced with their value. A simple example using your provided code:

```
>>> protocol = 'https'
>>> host = 'google.com'
>>> url = f'{protocol}://{host}'
>>> url
'https://google.com'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ikkuh. I believe I'm building with python 3.6

Comment: Python 3.6.4 indeed.

Comment: Can you run the small snippet I've provided in with your Python version?